# Getting a max without calling a view twice

Tags: sql, postgresql

The following query returns the user with the most friends. The view `allUserFriendCounts` lists all user names next to how many friends they have (for the sake of my question, I need to use this view). Running this query below seems to take twice as long as running `allUserFriendCounts`, because it has to run the latter twice.

Is there a way to re-write this more efficiently?

```
create or replace view getMaxFriendCount(name) as
    select f.name
    from allUserFriendCounts f
    where f.friendcount = (select max(committeecount) from allUserFriendCounts)
    GROUP BY name
;
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2.1

Comment: This has been the most effective

Comment: you have a type in your query, am I right? `userFriendCounts` should be `allUserFriendCounts`?

Comment: @RomanPekar you're right - changing now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you, your initial query is:

```
select f.name
from allUserFriendCounts f
where f.friendcount = (select max(c.friendcount) from allUserFriendCounts as c)
group by name
```

so you can use `dense_rank()` or `rank()` for your query:

```
with cte as (
    select
        *,
        rank() over(order by f.friendcount desc) as rnk
    from allUserFriendCounts as f
)
select name
from cte
where rnk = 1
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/bdb0b/3)</kbd>**

Comment: This is indeed twice as efficient! Thank you!